# How can I add my full, root Ubuntu 20.04 CLI server to a GitHub Repo for versioning, etc.?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, server, version-control

Is this a bad idea or is there a better way of approaching version control for my whole dedicated server?

My first attempt was *git init* and *git push* but I couldn't resolve error:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'main'
```

I tried several fixes and workarounds from StackOverflow.

So then I tried creating a repo from GitHub.com with just a test file, then cloning it, cd /, git add ., etc.. but I keep running into errors with it too.

```
fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

..is what I get after running *git clone git@github.com:hero/128GB.git .*

Any ideas on what I should do next? If I should continue this path or is there a better approach at version control for a server?

Comment: There are really two questions here. One is a debugging question about why you're getting certain errors, which could probably be answered if you gave some more details ("I tried several fixes" doesn't really tell us much). The other appears to be "should I use git to manage backups of an entire server?" to which the answer is an emphatic "no"; that is not the job git is designed for. Look into dedicated backup solutions, and versioned filesystems.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.